# timedelta неправильно считает

Tags: python, время

Есть такой код

```py
def late(now, classes, bus):
    now = now.split(':')
    now = timedelta(days=0, hours=int(now[0]), minutes=int(now[1]) + 5)
    classes = classes.split(':')
    classes = timedelta(hours=int(classes[0]), minutes=int(classes[1]))
    for i in bus:
        times = now + timedelta(minutes=15)
        print(times)
        if times < classes:
            return f'Выйти через {i} минут'
    return 'Опаздание'

print(late('12:00', '12:40', [0, 1, 4, 6, 25]))
```

Снизу пример, он считает успеешь ли ты до школы. Первое это сколько сейчас времени. Второй параметр это время начала уроков. Третий это через сколько приедет автобус(в минутах). При этом чтобы выйти нужно 5 минут и чтобы доехать 15. Все идеально но timedelta считает в pm, а не в am. Как можно дополнить код, чтобы timedelta считал правильно.

Comment: 12:00 это по вашему полдень или полночь? АМ или РМ?

Comment: AM, я написал про это в вопросе.

Comment: Сюрреалистичный код. 1) "Через сколько приедет автобус" - это как? Через сколько минут от какого времени? 2) Зачем вы в цикле прибавляете по 15 минут? Что это должно символизировать?

Comment: @Xle6yWek в вопросе написано непонятно. Даже не совсем понятно, в чем проблема.

Comment: timedelta - это объект, обозначающий различие между двумя моментами времени (промежутка времени). Вы его почему-то используете для указания конкретного времени. Вместо него нужно использовать datetime, а разницей между двумя объектами datetime уже будет timedelta.

Comment: А как надо-то. В этом и вопрос, я не знаю эту библиотеку. Как мне считать время правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписать код, чтобы не извращаться, а использовать `timedelta` по назначению:

```
import datetime as dt

def to_datetime(str_time):
    t = str_time.split(':')
    return dt.datetime.combine(dt.date.today(), dt.time(int(t[0]), int(t[1])))

def late(now, classes, bus):
    now = to_datetime(now) + dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
    classes = to_datetime(classes)
    for i in bus:
        times = now + dt.timedelta(minutes=15)
        if times < classes:
            return f'Выйти через {i} минут'
    return 'Опоздание'
```

```
print(late('12:00', '12:40', [0, 1, 4, 6, 25]))
# 'Выйти через 0 минут'
```

Comment: Как-бы по-изящнее соединять текущую дату + задаваемое время?

Comment: Там еще +5 минут к now в оригинале (на путь до автобуса). Можно конвертирование в datetime в отдельную функцию вынести, а так сильно изящнее вряд ли получится сделать.

Comment: @insolor Тоже только такая мысля и крутилась в голове. Собственно, так и сделал :)

Comment: Только вот `i` нигде не используется в теле цикла, даже если `classes` будет равен `16:30`, выдаст `Выйти через 0 минут`. Предположу, что функция не до конца написана.

Comment: Да, с функцией явно что-то не то. Еще расписание автобусов какое-то странное - всегда начинается от текущего момента, а по идее должен быть список моментов времени.